# Recursively create XML elements without static objects in Python?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do the best that I can but I apologize if it is as clear as mud.

I'm trying to build a XML structure, based off a skeleton, that is going to be several layers deep and I may need to create different elements from a parent element in which I will be adding data to. For example, I may have:

```
<List>
  <Mailing>
    <MailTo>
      <MailingInfo>
        <FirstName/>
        <LastName/>
        <Address1/>
        <City/>
        <State/>
        <Zip/>
      <Party>
        <Guests>
          <Guest>
            <FirstName/>
            <LastName/>
```

For each element, I'm iterating children, and catching specific element names to manually add data to, but I'm creating a number of code blocks for each depth. I have code that is looking something like:

```
# +7
for levelSeven in xmlSkeleton[rootChild.tag][subRootChild.tag][levelThree.tag][levelFour.tag][levelFive.tag][levelSix.tag].iterchildren():
    levelSevenSize = len([el.tag for el in xmlSkeleton[rootChild.tag][subRootChild.tag][levelThree.tag][levelFour.tag][levelFive.tag][levelSix.tag][levelSeven.tag].iterdescendants() if el.tag != None])
    if levelSevenSize == 0:
        levelSevenElement = objectify.SubElement(levelSixElement, levelSeven.tag)
    elif levelSevenSize > 0:
        levelSevenElement = objectify.SubElement(levelSixElement, levelSeven.tag)

        # +8
        for levelEight in xmlSkeleton[rootChild.tag][subRootChild.tag][levelThree.tag][levelFour.tag][levelFive.tag][levelSix.tag][levelSeven.tag].iterchildren():
            levelEightSize = len([el.tag for el in xmlSkeleton[rootChild.tag][subRootChild.tag][levelThree.tag][levelFour.tag][levelFive.tag][levelSix.tag][levelSeven.tag][levelEight.tag].iterdescendants() if el.tag != None])
            if levelEightSize == 0:
                levelEightElement = objectify.SubElement(levelSevenElement, levelEight.tag)
            elif levelEightSize > 0:
                levelEightElement = objectify.SubElement(levelSevenElement, levelEight.tag)

            # +9
            for levelNine in xmlSkeleton[rootChild.tag][subRootChild.tag][levelThree.tag][levelFour.tag][levelFive.tag][levelSix.tag][levelSeven.tag][levelEight.tag].iterchildren():
                levelNineSize = len([el.tag for el in xmlSkeleton[rootChild.tag][subRootChild.tag][levelThree.tag][levelFour.tag][levelFive.tag][levelSix.tag][levelSeven.tag][levelEight.tag][levelNine.tag].iterdescendants() if el.tag != None])
                if levelNineSize == 0:
                    levelNineElement = objectify.SubElement(levelEightElement, levelNine.tag)
                elif levelNineSize > 0:
                    levelNineElement = objectify.SubElement(levelEightElement, levelNine.tag)
                else:
                    pass
```

I'm really hoping there is a better way to iterate through a XML skeleton (for a schema specific structure) and add data while catching specific elements, such as "MailingInfo" or "Guestt" to add specific details for child elements from a dictionary. I tried a number of concoctions but have yet to be successful. I'm not sure if a class would be beneficial here or even how to approach that aside from a ridiculous number of nested code blocks like that.

The goal is to be able to continue to generate the XML structure and catch the same elements if the skeleton changes. Any input would be more than appreciated!

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with my question. My question has nothing to do with parsing, it has to do with creating elements going down the tree then continuing to build another branch from closer to the root. Please read the question before assuming it is a duplicate.

Comment: It would probably help to see samples of the actual input data and current problematic plus target output. Your code doesn't relay what you want to achieve - with nonsense conditions. My best guess at a solution would be a recursively called function `handleLevel(element)`, receiving at one point, e. g., `xmlSkeleton[rootChild.tag][subRootChild.tag][levelThree.tag]`, that executes the repeating block `for sub in element:` and `size=len([e for e in element[sub.tag] if e.tag!=None])` etc. until `handleLevel(element[sub.tag])` or break from recursion.